# how write an image in project folder in java

Tags: java, image, file, filepath

I have standalone application in netbeans and want to write file in project folder.
the below code working fine for any Local Drive

```
BufferedImage image = null;
        try {

            URL url = new URL("http://www.mkyong.com/image/mypic.jpg");
            image = ImageIO.read(url);

            ImageIO.write(image, "jpg",new File("D:\\out.jpg"));
            ImageIO.write(image, "gif",new File("D:\\out.gif"));
            ImageIO.write(image, "png",new File("D:\\out.png"));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Can i write the same image in project folder.
folder structure is

```
com.verma.rakesh.images
```

Comment: *"project folder"*  That means nothing when the app. is deployed.  Why not offer the user a `JFileChooser` to specify where to save it?

Comment: After the file chooser i want to  save file in com.verma.rakesh.images. Can i do it? if yes. then what is the best way.

Comment: *"i want to save file in `com.verma.rakesh.images`"*  I want a pony to fly.  Does not mean I will get what I want.  That package will likely be **in a Jar** at time of deployment. So again, it means nothing - it is not a real path.